How to Synthesize Indirect Light and Shadow Transparent Channels?

I want to keep the shadow channel of transparent and indirect light, but I don't want to lose the color of indirect light. I have tried many methods and can't solve it, but I don't know how to deal with this tricky problem.


What do you mean you don't want to lose the color? There is color in the image. And please do not use external links, expecially not for images. You can place images directly in your question and blend files can be uploaded here: https://blend-exchange.com (follow the instructions there to edit it into your question).

Apart from the comments from @GordonBrinkmann the link to your Google Drive file is locked and requesting access so can't be downloaded anyway!

I mean I want to get indirect light while getting shadows when compositing, and also need to keep the background transparent, because sometimes this is needed to simplify some workflow

Here is a potential workaround using Light linking and Light groups.
The main light source (white) is excluded from the plane while the red glow is kept to create the effect.
In post-processing the light are separated into light groups and combined to better adjust the final mood.
The dark pixel are also rendered transparent with a Set alpha node. But I'm not a specialist of transparent background so maybe someone will come up with a better solution than mine.



Thank you for your help my brother.

My pleasure. If it works for you, don't forget to upvote and/or mark the case as resolved (green tick) for future viewers.
